# When using range.find to find bold text it won't find if the entire selection is bold!

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to extract bold text using the range.find method and all is peachy except if the entire range is actually bold (not likely to happen much, it's more of an edge condition).

```
With rngFindRange.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Font.Bold = True
Do
    .Execute

    If Not .Found Then
         Exit Do
    End If

    'do something with found text'

    Set rngFindRange = ActiveDocument.Range(rngFindRange.End + 1, Selection.End)

Loop
```

The above matches bold text right at the start or right at the end, even both but not when the entire range is bold. I think I might have to test the range.font.bold = true before searching through the range. What does stackoverflow think?

Answer (score 6):

This should find any bold text:

```
Sub SearchBoldText()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisDocument.Range(0, 0)
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Font.Bold = True
        While .Execute
            rng.Select
            rng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guillermooo, not exactly what I was after but a useful technique none-the-less, I'll give you an up vote for that :-)

Comment: That is if I had a reputation of 15 I guess :-(

Comment: Can you post your whole sub then? What do you need exactly?