# Copy and paste Word Table Title into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a word document with multiple tables. I have some script in excel which loops through the word doc and extracts all of the tables in word and brings it in into excel. The script allows the user to choose which table to begin at (just fyi). What I am trying to do is also have the script bring over the title of that table (it's in Bold and Underline) and append it to the adjacent column. And to also name the header of that column "Section title". Some of the Titles have words following the title and then the table itself. And then some just have the Title and then the table immediately after. What I need is the Bolded Underlined Title.

Here is what the word document looks like:

[image]

Here is what I need it to be:

[image]

Here is what I have currently:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer
Dim wdApp As Object, wdTable As Object
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
Dim thisText As String, newText As String



On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table(s) to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")  'Enter table number to start at
    End If


    resultRow = 1

For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
With .Tables(tableStart)
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            thisText = .Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text
            newText = Replace(thisText, Chr(13), vbCrLf)
            newText = Replace(newText, Chr(7), vbNullString)
            Cells(resultRow, iCol) = newText
        Next iCol
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next iRow
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: While you provided a lot of detail, you have not provided *your attempts to solve the issue you face*. No where in this code is any attempt to extract the title you reference. So, you are essentially asking us to write the code for you, which is outside the scope of SO. That said, I just considered something like this recently in my own work and the only thing I could thing of was to loop through the text and compare the character fonts. In your case, loop backward from the start of the table range, look for bold & underline text and capture the text from end to begin to get the title.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975033/when-using-range-find-to-find-bold-text-it-wont-find-if-the-entire-selection-is) could be a good place to start.

Given what you have provided, you can search for bold & underlined text and enter the selection into excel via a loop or your preference.

Below is the code from the link (to save time) with some edits to work with excel:

```
Sub SearchTitles()

    Dim wordDoc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Integer

    Set wordDoc = Documents("your document filename")  ' open the doc prior to running
    Set rng = wordDoc.Range(0, 0)    

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With

    For row = 1 To lastRow
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Format = True
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
            While .Execute
                rng.Select
                rng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd

                ' Do something here with selection
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name").Range("E" & row).Value = Selection

            Wend
        End With
        Set rng = Selection.Range
    Next   

End Sub
```

This solution is very naive as it assumes there is no other bold & underlined text in your document, but hopefully its a place to start... best of luck