# VBA insert carriage return between bold and unbold text

Tags: vba, carriage-return, text-formatting

I have a word document that is a transcription of an interview. The moderators comments are in bold and respondents comments are not bold. It is a long continuous run on of bold and un-bold text. I need to add a carriage return so that there is a blank line between the moderator and the respondents questions. I found the code below to insert a carriage return between specific text, but I don't know how to change it to insert between bold and un-bold text.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Test()
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Foo" & Chr(11) & "Bar"
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975033/when-using-range-find-to-find-bold-text-it-wont-find-if-the-entire-selection-is

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, it uses one sub to insert a break after bold text, and then calls another sub to do the same for nonbold text. I used the constant 'vbCrLf' which stands for Visual Basic Carriage Return Line Feed, it's equal to Chr(13) + Chr(10), and I believe it's the best practice for compatibility when inserting a line break in a document as opposed to Chr(11).

```
Sub InsertBreakAfterBold()
    'Select entire document
    Selection.WholeStory

    'Make each .Method belong to Selection.Find for readability
    With Selection.Find
        'Set search criteria for bold font
        .Font.Bold = True
        'Find next occurrence
        .Execute

        'Each time bold text is found add a line break to the end of it then find the next one
        Do While .Found
            Selection.Text = Selection.Text + vbCrLf
            .Execute
        Loop

    End With

    'Repeat process for nonbold text
    Call InsertBreakAfterNonbold
End Sub

Sub InsertBreakAfterNonbold()
    Selection.WholeStory

    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Execute

        Do While .Found
            Selection.Text = Selection.Text + vbCrLf
            .Execute 
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

Microsoft's VBA reference was my biggest resource to make this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word

Comment: Amazing! That did the trick.  You must be a wizard because that churned through 50 pages of messy text and came out  perfect.  Can't say thank you enough for your help with that.

Comment: @LansP8 You're absolutely welcome, thank you for the compliment. I'm glad it did the trick for you; I can't imagine doing that manually for 50 pages.