# Simple Question - Range Object - Finding a Bold Version of a Word of Interest

Tags: vba, ms-word

I noticed this line of code elsewhere:

```
If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Title") Then
```

I have looked, yet find no readily accessible guidance on the following, which is my question:

What do I need to do to the above line of code in order to cause it to look only for **Title** and not Title?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975033/when-using-range-find-to-find-bold-text-it-wont-find-if-the-entire-selection-is

Comment: Yes I have looked at and used that also.  I will keep searching and when I find what I am looking for I will post it.

Comment: For how to use Word's "Find" I highly recommend investigating Word's advanced built-in Find functionality. The quickest way to get there is Ctrl+H, click the "Find" tab, then the "More" button. Investigate/research all these options to get an idea of what "Find" can do. If you need the functionality in code, record a macro while executing "Find" with the required settings to get the basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content

    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting   'clear any existing format settings
        .Font.Bold = True  'looking for Bold text only
        If .Execute(FindText:="Title") Then
            Debug.Print "found it!"
            rng.Select 'rng is now the found text...
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```